# multiplicative digital root of a number using loops

Tags: python

I need to find the multiplicative digital root of a number in python using only loops.

something that does the same as the below code but using loops:

```
print("multiplicative digital root of a number Calculator")
print("-"*50)

num = input("Enter a number: ")

def droot(num):
    if len(num) == 1:
        return num
    else:
        sum = 0
        for i in num:
            sum += int(i)
        num = str(sum)
        return droot(num)

print("The digital root of ", num, " is: ", droot(num))
```

Comment: That code does use a loop at the end of the function.

Comment: i know but i dont need functions, just loops. thats what my homework wants

Comment: are you looking for non-recursive implementation of above code snippet?

Comment: basically all i want is a snippet that calculates the multiplicative digital root of a number using only loops and no functions

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're looking for something like this:

```
number = 9876; #Example
divider = 1;
digits = []
answer = -1
while true:
    value = 1
    while number % divider != 0: #Fills list with digits
        digits.append(number % divider)
        divider = divider * 10
    while list.len() != 0: # Empty list for next iteration
        value = value * list[0]
        list.remove(0) # The elements will always be 0, as the first one is constantly removed
    number = value # Change for next iteration
    if value == value % 10: # If there's only a single digit left, you've got it
        answer = value # Finish up, close
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def d_root(num):

   temp=num

   c=0

   while 1:

      p=1

      c=c+1

      while temp!=0:

         rem=temp%10

         p=p*rem

         temp=int(temp/10)

      if p<10:

         print("Multiplicative Presistance ",c)

         print("Multiplicative Digital Root ",p)

         break

      temp=p

n=int(input("Enter any Number "))

d_root(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def digital_root(num):

   temp=num
   while(1):
      p=1
      while temp!=0:
         rem=temp%10
         p=p*rem
         temp=int(temp/10)
      if p<10:
         print(p)
         break
      temp=p
num=int(input("Enter number"))
digital_root(num)
```

Comment: Please tell us about you problem.

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Random reminder [these aren't deletable from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/6296561)