# Find no of occurrences of a function from another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Question: " If all digits of a number n are multiplied by each other repeating with the product, the one-digit number obtained at last is called the multiplicative digital root of n. The number of times digits need to be multiplied to reach one digit is called the multiplicative persistence of n.
Example: `86 -> 48 -> 32 -> 6 (MDR 6, MPersistence 3)`
`341 -> 12->2 (MDR 2, MPersistence 2)`
Using the function prodDigits() of previous exercise write functions MDR() and MPersistence() that input a number and return its multiplicative digital root and
multiplicative persistence respectively"

```py
    no=int(input())
    
    def prodDigits(n):
        prod=1
        while n>0:
            prod=prod*(n%10)
            n=n//10
        return prod
    
    def mdr(n):
        if n<10:
            return n
        else:
            return mdr(prodDigits(n))
        
        
    def MPersistence(n):
        count=0
        while():
            count=count+1
        return count
    
    
    print(mdr(no))
    print(MPersistence(no))
```

I am not able to get how can I count mdr() function call from MPersistence() function. I have tried few conditions inside while loop but all are resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: In general, you can't.  `mdr` needs to count the iterations.  `MPersistance` needs to access that number and report it.

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/58423636/6692898

Comment: There is nothing in the task description saying that ``MPersistence`` has to work by counting/inspecting ``mdr`` recursion. What makes you think you have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not possible – `MPersistence` will only ever run *before* or *after* `MDR`. At a minimum, `MDR` would need to be modified to track iterations itself, which raises problems how to safely exchange the result between two functions. Ideally, `MPersistence` should work by independently computing the chain of digit multiplications.

To avoid code duplication, use one function that computes *both* digital root and persistence; as needed, provide convenience functions to return each component directly.

```py
def mdrp(n: int):
    """
    Compute the multiplicative persistence and digital root of ``n``
    """
    if n < 10:
        return 0, n
    else:
        persistence, digital_root = mdrp(prodDigits(n))
        return persistence + 1, digital_root

def MDR(n):
    return mdrp(n)[1]

def MPersistence(n):
    return mdrp(n)[0]
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's giving "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error after execution.

Comment: @AmritaGhatak There was a typo when recursing, calling an undefined function instead of itself. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine now.But I am not getting the else part logic why persistence and digital_root returning 2 different value.Can you please give the insight what is happening internally.
else:
        persistence, digital_root = mdrp(prodDigits(n))
        return persistence + 1, digital_root

Comment: mdrp returns both persistence and digital root. The else clause simply unpacks them from the recursive call, and increments the persistence-which is the level of recursion, i.e. it must grow by one for every recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another function to count the function calls. MisterMiyagi's idea is to have a counter inside the function itself, and return both the persistence and the digital root at every function call, unpacking the result at the end.

I think a simpler way would be to have a counter as a global variable and increase its value inside the function on every call:

```
def mdr(n):
    if n<10:
        return n
    else:
        return mdr(prodDigits(n))
        globals()['persistence'] += 1

persistence = 0
print(mdr(86), persistence)  # 6 3
```

This approach looks simpler but there's one thing to keep in mind: the counter has to be initialized every time before calling the function:

```
print(msr(341), persistence) # 2 5 Wrong result

persistence = 0
print(msr(341), persistence) # 2 2 Right result
```

This would not be a **pure function**, because it depends on and alters non-local variables.

Comment: Actually, in my assignment, the question is to write functions MDR() and MPersistence() that input a number and return its multiplicative digital root and multiplicative persistence respectively. So, maybe I am bound to use MPersistence() function

Comment: I have tried this but it's giving me print(mdr(86), persistence) ...6 0 as output..I'm not getting why.

Comment: Consider to prefer the global keyword instead of editing the globals dictionary.